# Proving that for $a\in\Bbb{Z}$, $a^2\mid a$ iff $a\in\{-1, 0, 1\}$. My first argument seems shaky, my second argument seems overly simple.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Suppose $a\in\Bbb{Z}$. Then $a^2\mid a$ iff $a\in\{-1, 0, 1\}$.

Showing $P\Rightarrow Q$.

For the sake of contradiction, assume $a^2\mid a$ and $a\not\in\{-1, 0, 1\}$. Then $a=a^2n, n\in\Bbb{Z}, n\not=0$.

Dividing both sides by $a$ gives us $an=1$ and therefore $a=\frac{1}{n}$.

If $n=1$ or $n=-1$ then $a\in\{-1, 0, 1\}$, a contradiction.

If $n\not=1$ or $n\not=-1$ then $a\not\in\Bbb{Z}$, a contradiction.

Now, showing $Q\Rightarrow P$.

Assume $a\in\{-1, 0, 1\}$.

If $a=-1$, we have $1\mid -1$, obviously true. If $a=0$, we have $0\mid 0$, obviously true. If $a=1$, we have $1\mid 1$, obviously true.

$\blacksquare$

I'm certain there is a simpler way to prove this but I want to know if the arguments I used are valid. I'm worried there is something wrong with my assumption that $n\not=0$ and I'm concerned by how trivial the second argument seems.

Comment: Yes the second argument is trivial, that's OK ! Three cases to check, you check them, you're good.

The first argument is almost perfect: you are right that it's not correct to assume $n\neq 0$. But it comes automatically however since otherwise  $a=0$...

Comment: "*dividing both sides by $a$*"  My professor would have been very disappointed to see division in a context like this.  Avoiding division, I would note that $a\mid b \implies |a|\leq |b|$ and so $a^2\mid a\implies |a^2|\leq |a|$, but we know from induction that $|n^2|>|n|$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $|n|>1$.

Comment: $a^2|a\iff (a=0 \lor a|1)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes... that is the *result* that the OP is trying to prove.  All you did was restate the question title.

Comment: @JMoravitz:  the question title doesn’t say $a|1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I expand here on my comment)

Yes the second argument is trivial, that's OK ! Three cases to check, you check them, you're good.

The first argument is almost perfect: you are right that it's not correct to assume $≠0$. But it comes automatically however since otherwise $=0$...

Finally, you can simplify this first argument by removing the contradiction, and working by case separation. Assume  $a^2 \mid a$. Then there is $n\in \Bbb Z$ such that $a = a^2n$. Either $a=0$ and the proof is over, or $a \neq 0$ and you can divide, giving $1 = an$, so $a \mid 1$ so $a=\pm 1$, and the proof is over too.

Comment: "*such that $a=a^2n$.*"  To avoid referring to division, continue as $a(1-an)=0$ which in turn implies $a=0$ or $(1-an)=0$, which lets you continue from there as you had.

Comment: Yeah you're right, nice way to put it !